# how can I configure the context switch time slice in Linux?

Tags: linux, pthreads

I have following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* a(void* ptr) {
while(1){
    printf("1");
    printf("2");
    printf("3");
    printf("4");
}
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        pthread_t t;
        pthread_create(&t, NULL, a, 0);
        while(1){
            printf("a");
            printf("b");
            printf("c");
            printf("d");
    }
    pthread_join(t, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

the result of this code is "abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd1234123412341234..........."
but I want them to be mixed like "ab12c3d4a1bcda23b......"
how can I configure the scheduling time slice of a thread?
is this possible?

thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

You can modify scheduling behaviour by setting the sched param (`pthread_setschedparam(3)`) to for example `SCHED_RR` (RR means Round Robin). There is `SCHED_FIFO`, `SCHED_RR` and `SCHED_OTHER` with `SCHED_OTHER` being the default.